# Relocate pointer passed as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a method that takes a single `unsigned char*` as a parameter.

```
int MyClass::MyMethod(unsigned char* resultArray)
```

That parameter is allocated by an external .NET application and passed but the value is expected to change based on the result.

In the body of the method, I call a third party API that returns an array in a similar way.

```
ThirdPartyAPI::GetResult(result);
int size = result.GetSize();
unsigned char* temp = new unsigned char[size];
result.GetData(temp);
```

Now, my temp variable is a filled array with the results I need to return to C#. How do I do that?
I tried simple `resultArray = result` but that only returns an empty array. Since there's no way for C# application to know the size prior to calling my method, it must be initialized to a random length or sent in empty and resized in my method.
So if I could so something like `resultArray = new unsigned char[size]` to resize it then I could avoid the copy but that throws an exception.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a say in the signature of the method? Like is it possible for you to change it to take a different type than `char *`?

Comment: @smac89 of MYMethod, yes, but I choose to return unsigned char* since that is what GetData from the third party api is returning. What would you suggest?

Comment: my method needs to return int value that is sucess/error-id and the full value of the `temp` array I've shown.

Comment: See my answer. I have a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a say in the method signature, then change your function to this

```
int MyClass::MyMethod(unsigned char** resultArray)
```

then you can do

```
*resultArray = result;
```

To call this method you would now have to pass the address of the pointer rather than just the pointer

```
MyClass m;
char *str;
m.MyMethod(&str);
```

### Alternative solution

```
char* MyClass::MyMethod(int *status);
```

With this signature, you can just return the string and modify the int parameter to contain the status of the call

```
MyClass m;
int status;
char *str = m.MyMethod(&status);
if (status == 0) {}
```

Comment: How would I pass that parameter from C#? Currently it's called like this:

Comment: byte[] destinationArray = new byte[1024];
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* templateBytes = destinationArray)
    {
        result = client.MyMethod(templateBytes);
    }
}

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that alternative solution as well, that may work. I would have to return size as well, I assume, but it could work.